# AngularJS Typescript grid ui - setting function as a column value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have the following ui grid in my angularJS app"

```
this.resultGrid = {
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { name: 'Id', field: 'id' },
        { name: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        { name: 'Street', field: 'street' },
        { name: 'Postcode', field: 'postcode' },
        { name: 'City', field: 'city' },
        { name: 'Country', field: 'country' },
        { name: 'In System', field: 'inSys()' }
    ],
    data: [{ city: "Warsaw", country: "Poland", id: "123456789", name: "Company 1", postcode: "00-122", street: "Waszyngtona", inSys: this.inSys(id); }, //compilation error - cannot find name "id"
{ city: "London", country: "UK", id: "987654321", name: "Company 2", street: "Downtown" }]
};
```

and the function I want to call inside this controller:

```
inSys = (id: string) => {
    if (id== null || id.length == 0)
        return false;

    return this.myService.recordExistsInSys(id);
}
```

I have not found any example of how to pass a function as a `ui-grid` column value in typescript. Any ideas how to deal with it?

Comment: Did it recognized `inSys` function?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and for me this worked:

```
this.resultGrid = {
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
    enableSorting: true,
    context: {
          inSys: (row) => {
              /*do something with row*/
    }
    columnDefs: [
        { name: 'Id', field: 'id' },
        { name: 'Name', field: 'name' },
        { name: 'Street', field: 'street' },
        { name: 'Postcode', field: 'postcode' },
        { name: 'City', field: 'city' },
        { name: 'Country', field: 'country' },
        { name: 'In System', field: 'context.inSys(MODEL_COL_FIELD)' }
    ],
    data: [{ city: "Warsaw", country: "Poland", id: "123456789", name: "Company 1", postcode: "00-122", street: "Waszyngtona", inSys: this.inSys(id); }, //compilation error - cannot find name "id"
{ city: "London", country: "UK", id: "987654321", name: "Company 2", street: "Downtown" }]
};
```

I didn't try your code but maybe this could help you.